# Structuring SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I have the below requirement to generate a report.

```
TASKTYPE.TaskTypeName,TASKWIP.DMTaskState_key FROM MercuryProd.TEAMSPACE.F_DMCaseWIP WIP,
MercuryProd.TEAMSPACE.F_DMTaskWIP TASKWIP,
MercuryProd.TEAMSPACE.D_DMDataField_BM_ExternalCaseIdentifier EXTID,
MercuryProd.TEAMSPACE.D_DMTaskType TASKTYPE
WHERE WIP.DMCase_key=TASKWIP.DMCase_key
AND EXTID.BM_ExternalCaseIdentifier_key=WIP.VMAE_BM_ExternalCaseIdentifier_key
AND TASKTYPE.DMTaskType_key=TASKWIP.DMTaskType_key
AND EXTID.BM_ExternalCaseIdentifier='BMAX5C62970'
--AND TASKTYPE.DMTaskType_key=9 AND TASKWIP.DMTaskState_key=2
--AND TASKTYPE.DMTaskType_key=10 AND TASKWIP.DMTaskState_key=0
```

[image]

If you look at the last two lines of sql, that's critical. I need all records satisfying both condition. A case type can have multiple corresponding child records in the taskwip table. I need to filter only those cases where within the child records both criteria meets. That's task 9 with state 2 and task 10 with state 0. What I have given here is an example data for one record. There will be multiple records similarly, like for another case key, multiple child record where task 9 with state 3 not 2, and task 10 with state 2 not 0. The report should not show this record.

I am happy if you can develop a query in any of the DB language whether its slq server, Oracle, mysql. I am interested more on the logic than the language format.

[image]

Because as seen in the result set, for this case key, there is a tasktype 10 with state 0 and task type 9 with state 2.

Comment: Well I guess the answer will depend on your database/version... SQL Server or Oracle  ?

Comment: And also, what you are asking is unclear. Do you want some kind of ordering in the aggregated result?

Comment: In SQL Server 2017+  string_agg()   If <=2016 you may want stuff/XML approach

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti I have edited my original post to make it more clear. I am not actually interested in the listagg function from oracle or for xml path in sql server. I would be happy to understand the logic to put the requirement in query format. Say for data record 1 in table A has 4 child records in table B. I need to get all such records in table A where one of the child record type in state 2 and other type in state 0.

Comment: @Tejash I have edited my question to make it more clear about the logic part I'm looking for. Would you mind taking a look and let me know if you need any further details?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks much for your suggestion. This is not really the full-blown query. I just written a random query to make understand the logic I'm looking for. But agree, using natural join here would make the query standard and more readable especially when its too long, even though there is no difference it can make from a performance perspective.

Comment: @vipinev : but it *does* make a performance difference in terms of a colleague or a future reader/maintainer that is attempting to decipher what the query is doing...  how much time it takes them to decode the statement. That alone is enough reason to ditch the old school comma syntax for join operations, never mind the possibility we might want to later add an outer join

Comment: @spencer7593 Definitely yes, I agree with your point. This query was just written for the purpose of explaining the scenario, but I will make sure to follow the standards when its used in the application. Also I think exists clause was what exactly I was looking for. I have managed to develop this with two exists clause. Thanks much for the support, really appreciated!

Comment: @vipinev my first cut at an answer didn't cut it, ... the two different TASKTYPE rows are going to be related to two different  TASKWIP rows.  I edited my answer, to show a JOIN in the correlated subqueries.

Comment: @spencer7593 Thank you. The exists clause was the key though. I could manage to develop my query with extra logic applied in it. The key thing I wasn't sure about is how two conditions can be satisfied for the child records!

Comment: @vipinev if the question has been answered to your satisfaction, then you can "select" an answer, so the question doesn't add to the escalating count of "not yet answered" questions on StackOverflow.  (it looks like of the previous *nine* questions you've asked, only *one* of them has been answered... not a great track record.)  and yah `EXISTS` is a powerful tool to have in the SQL toolbelt.

Comment: @spencer7593 Sure. I have marked it as an accepted answer. I will focus more on how a question can be framed and put it in the right place with tags. I'm more like a beginner as I haven't extensively used this platform but will try to catch-up things soon :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specification isn't clear; I'm guessing, and this is just a guess, that we want to return rows ONLY if BOTH of a couple specific rows exist.

One option is to use correlated subqueries in an `EXISTS` predicate.

for example, something like this:

```
       TASKTYPE.TaskTypeName
     , TASKWIP.DMTaskState_key 

  FROM MercuryProd.TEAMSPACE.F_DMCaseWIP  WIP

  JOIN MercuryProd.TEAMSPACE.F_DMTaskWIP  TASKWIP
    ON TASKWIP.DMCase_key = WIP.DMCase_key

  JOIN MercuryProd.TEAMSPACE.D_DMDataField_BM_ExternalCaseIdentifier  EXTID
    ON EXTID.BM_ExternalCaseIdentifier_key = WIP.VMAE_BM_ExternalCaseIdentifier_key

  JOIN MercuryProd.TEAMSPACE.D_DMTaskType  TASKTYPE
    ON TASKTYPE.DMTaskType_key = TASKWIP.DMTaskType_key

 WHERE EXTID.BM_ExternalCaseIdentifier = 'BMAX5C62970'
   AND EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                  FROM MercuryProd.TEAMSPACE.D_DMTaskType  tt92 
                 WHERE tt92.DMTaskType_key     = 9
                   AND TASKWIP.DMTaskState_key = 2
              )
   AND EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                  FROM MercuryProd.TEAMSPACE.D_DMTaskType  tt10
                 WHERE tt10.DMTaskType_key     = 10
                   AND TASKWIP.DMTaskState_key = 0
              )
```

Note that it doesn't matter what value the subqueries return, the EXISTS is just checking if at least one row is return.

Note that this doesn't restrict which rows from TASKTYPE are returned. If we want to limit the return to just specific matching rows, we can add to the ON clause of the TASKTYPE join, or to the WHERE clause ...

```
   AND (  ( TASKTYPE.DMTaskType_key = 9  AND TASKWIP.DMTaskState_key = 2 )
       OR ( TASKTYPE.DMTaskType_key = 10 AND TASKWIP.DMTaskState_key = 0 )
       )
```

---

There are other query patterns we could use; we could do a single EXISTS like this:

```
   AND EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                  FROM MercuryProd.TEAMSPACE.D_DMTaskType  ttx
                 WHERE ( ttx.DMTaskType_key = 9  AND TASKWIP.DMTaskState_key = 2 )
                    OR ( ttx.DMTaskType_key = 10 AND TASKWIP.DMTaskState_key = 0 )
                HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ttx.DMTaskType_key) = 2
              )
```

**EDIT**

The first pattern demonstrated isn't sufficient. That requires both TASKTYPE rows to be related to the same TASKWIP row, and that can't happen because each TASKTYPE row require a different value from the TASKWIP row.

We would need to do the join in the correlated subqueries.

Something along these lines:

```
   AND EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                  FROM MercuryProd.TEAMSPACE.F_DMTaskWIP   tw92
                  JOIN MercuryProd.TEAMSPACE.D_DMTaskType  tt92 
                    ON tt92.DMTaskType_key   = tw92.DMTaskType_key
                   AND tt92.DMTaskType_key   = 9
                 WHERE tw92.DMTaskState_key  = 2
                   AND tw92.DMCase_key       = WIP.DMCase_key
              )
   AND EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                  FROM MercuryProd.TEAMSPACE.F_DMTaskWIP   tw10
                  JOIN MercuryProd.TEAMSPACE.D_DMTaskType  tt10
                    ON tt10.DMTaskType_key   = tw10.DMTaskType_key
                   AND tt10.DMTaskType_key   = 10
                 WHERE tw10.DMTaskState_key  = 0
                   AND tw10.DMCase_key       = WIP.DMCase_key
              )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's what exactly I'm looking for. The first one was sufficient for me to understand the logic. Now I have developed the query based on my requirement - and its working as expected. Great support! Appreciate that!

Answer (score 0):

For oracle, you can use the listagg like below

```
   SELECT DM_Case_Key,listagg(TaskTypeName,',') within group (order by DMTaskType_key)
   over (partition by DM_Case_Key) as Tasks
   FROM your_data
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have edited my question to make it more clear what I'm looking for. I am not looking for a syntactical expression to group the records. I am keen around the logic. Say for data record 1 in table A has 4 child records in table B. I need to get all such records in table A where one of the child record type in state 2 and other type in state 0.